# How to set domain in field on page load?

Tags: cross-domain, onchange, odoo-8, formview

I have set domain in second field by onchange of one field. but after page refresh, domain get lost as sets by onchane and again we need to update first field to get domain in second field. What's the sol? I am using Odoo-v8.

```
@api.multi
    def onchange_type(self, is_company):        
        if is_company:
            domain = {'title': [('domain', '=', 'partner')]}
        else:
            domain = {'title': [('domain', '=', 'contact')]}
        return {'domain': domain}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def _set_required_boolean(self):
    # your logic goes here for is_student
    if is_student:
        return True
    else:
        return False
required_boolean = fields.Boolean(default=_set_required_boolean)
```

Instead of onchange use default